# On click of li get fade in, fade out with delay/pause effect using "rel" attribute in single div

Tags: tabs, delay, fadein, fadeout, rel

I have 5 rows of same set of `ul` `li` as following. Whenever I click on any of `li` *(**`li`*** *will be selected)* it will open/show a `popover` or a `div` which fade in and pause for few time and thereafter fade out. I am using the same class for `ul` and its parent `div`.

```
<div class="choices">
    <ul class="question-choices"> 
        <li><a rel="0" href="#tab1" class="active">a</a></li>
        <li><a rel="1" href="#tab2">b</a></li>
        <li><a rel="2" href="#tab3">c</a></li>
        <li><a rel="3" href="#tab4">d</a></li>
        <li><a rel="4" href="#tab5">e</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="tab1” class=”content”>aaaa</div>
<div id="tab2” class=”content”>bbbb</div>
<div id="tab3” class=”content”>cccc</div>
<div id="tab4” class=”content”><dddd/div>
<div id="tab5” class=”content”>eeee</div>
```

I found this method and try to use it:

```
$(". content ").hide();
    $("ul.question-choices li").click(function() {
    $("ul. question-choices li").removeClass("active"); 
    $(this).addClass("active");
$(". content ").hide(); 

var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
$(activeTab).fadeIn();
```

How to I add fade in, fade out and pause effect in it. How to use **`“rel”`** attribute for it. Is it possible that I can use only one `div` for all `popover` and change it content via html/text.

Kindly let me know how to achieve it or any simple example (as I am still learning) where I can find it.

Comment: Don't misuse the `rel` attribute for this. If you are using HTML5, make use of `data-*` attributes instead.